# Subtract any number from previous number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops

Suppose that we have this matrix in MATLAB:

```
a = [1,3,3,4,6];
```

I want subtract any number from previous number so we have `a_out` as output:

```
a_out = [1,2,0,1,2];
```

How can I do this without using loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `diff([0 a])`.

`diff` computes the "Differences and Approximate Derivatives", and as you also want the difference between 0 and your first element, you need to concatenate a 0 to your vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,3,3,4,6];

a_out = [a 0] - [0 a];
a_out = a_out(1:end-1);
```

Comment: One should keep in mind, that on execution level it will be a for loop.

Except your code gets translated to FPGA